# Swift - how to run multiply timers?

Tags: ios

In my app I have a view, and I want this view to be dismissed everytime it is shown after 8 seconds. In order to do that I created a timer inside view creation function that hides view after firing. It works. But in some cases I want to present two copies of the view I want both be dismissed after time it was created +8 seconds. Issue is that timer works only once - it hides one copy of view, and second remains on screen

My code is

```
 func presentShowStatusShort(text text:String) {

    pointsShort = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("helperShowStatusShort", owner: self, options: nil).first! as! helperShowStatusShort
    pointsShort?.frame.size.width = self.view.bounds.width

    if pointsShortOnScreen {

        pointsShort!.frame.origin.y = pointsShort!.frame.origin.y + 39

    }

    pointsShort?.text.text = "\(text.uppercaseString)"
    pointsShort!.dismissButton.addTarget(self, action: "dismissShowStatusShort", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(8, target: self, selector: "dismissShowStatusShort", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    pointsShortOnScreen = true

    view.addSubview(pointsShort!)

}

func dismissShowStatusShort() {

    pointsShortOnScreen = false

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {

        self.pointsShort?.frame.origin.y = (self.pointsShort?.frame.origin.y)! - 64

        }, completion:  {
            finished in

            self.pointsShort?.removeFromSuperview()
    })


}
```

Comment: for me title and the question itself tell something different. So you want to use only one timer to dismiss both views, or use a timer per view ?

Comment: just use an array to store all timers, stop and remove them when it's desired

Answer (score 1):

From an OOP point of view you should create a class to help you with this. The class would own the timer and maintain a reference to the view. When the timer expires it calls a callback, passing itself as the parameter, so the controller can get the associated view and dismiss it.

All of the instances of this class would be stored in an array instance variable on the controller so you can add multiple and remove each one once it expires.